# create new elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

In my Spring web application, for customer registration page I am adding and removing divs containing text, img and a-ref elements. When I write the code inside the same jsp the page works perfectly but according to my requirement when I try to put javascript code into a js file and import it and click add button a new div is inserted along with script code as given below,

[image: in the image below when i press the '+' sign button i intend to call a js function which adds a row with text field and a close button and an img, but instead of this it shows the code]

the js function I am using to add a div is..

```
function addInputBox() { 
var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv'); 
var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
numi.value = num;
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
var divIdName = 'my'+num+'Div';

newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName); 
var htmlString  = '<div style="margin-top: 5px"><input type="text"name="service_name" title="Service Name" maxlength="200" style="width:400px;vertical-align:middle;"/>'+ 
                            '<a href="javascript:removeInputBox(\''+divIdName+'\')"><img src="<c:url value="/resources/img/common/x.png" />" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-left: 5px"/></a>'+
                            '<img src="<c:url value="/resources/img/ope/new.png" />" style="vertical-align:middle;margin:2px 0 0 2px;margin-left: 5px" /> </div> ';

newdiv.innerHTML = htmlString; 
ni.appendChild(newdiv);}
```

any idea what may went wrong? any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: @bipen may be you are right, escaping those quote is a tedious job, I tried to clone the div seperately and it worked but the problem is when i try to insert new element in between those elements inside that div.it is displayed in new line for each div. Is there any way to append div in same line? BTW <c:url> is JSTL tags used to redirect to given url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty sure the script is there , because you are not escaping the  quotation..try this

```
<img src="<c:url value=\"/resources/img/common/x.png\" />" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-left: 5px"/></a>'+
                        '<img src="<c:url value=\"/resources/img/ope/new.png\" />" style="vertical-align:middle;margin:2px 0 0 2px;margin-left: 5px" />
```

missing escape..."\" in ur img tag....

not sure wat c:url  is...

hope this helps